# change outputText to inputText in JSF-html using ajax component

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, xhtml

I  want reach something like this, lets have a:

```
 <h:outputText id="name" value="#{Bean.foo.name}"/>
```

in a some  column in datatable and i want achieve by single clicking on this output text on layout in order change to:

```
<h:inputText value="#{Bean.foo.name}"/>
```

in other words by clicking  on output text to change to a classic input field, Is there any way to do this with ajax component, can anybody give me some concept about this, i will be very greatful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a problem to use a PrimeFaces component here it is; an [inplace component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml)

Comment: yes this is what i looking for,hope this will works at me,but thanks a lot

Comment: Yes nice suggestion. Otherwise use link with f:ajax and render area and have inputtext be rendered=true and link rendered=false

Comment: how can i fired some action with clicking to save button in this inline component? now nothing happend when i click on this also i have there included a <p:ajax> tag